# Safari 15 crashes while rendering canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari

Safari 15 on macOS, iPhone and iPad will crash while rendering with canvas. Any solution for this? This used to work on the previous Safari.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script language="javascript">
function init2() {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.width = "800px";
    canvas.style.height = "600px";
    canvas.width = 1600;
    canvas.height = 1200;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '48px system-ui';
  ctx.fillText('Hello World, 你好中文', 10, 50);
}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init2()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To replace the font can fix the problem.

Comment: For webkit bugs: https://bugs.webkit.org/ However it seems that it has been fixed already in latest Technology Preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the solution for me is to replace the font "system-ui" to "san-serif" which fixed my issue. Also, in Safari Technical Preview and Beta 3 has already fixed this bug and schedule to release later in Oct. 2021.